# How to remove the scroll limit fade (edge-overshot effect)?

Tags: gnome, 15.10, gtk3, scrolling

When scrolling in any list of files or some other apps, when the bottom or top is reached, ubuntu displays some kind of "fade" effect like with scrolling in android noting the limit.

How can this effect be disabled?

This effect was not displayed before Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a feature of Ubuntu, or Gnome, it's the underlying GTK3 effect triggered by the **edge-overshot** event https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkScrolledWindow.html#GtkScrolledWindow-edge-overshot.

If the effect does not look good with your theme or you find it annoying, then you will need to edit the `overshoot` CSS class in the GTK+ theme. (If it messes up the display then it is a bug in the theme and should be reported to the theme author).

To disable the overshoot effect you can manually edit the GTK+ theme to tweak the CSS rule.

1. Find out the current GTK+ theme in use. As I have a custom theme, the standard System Settings did not show the correct theme name. To see the correct GTK+ theme I used [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/GnomeTweakTool), installable with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
2. In Gnome Tweak Tool Under *Appearance* you will see the current GTK+ theme, for example `MBuntu-Y`. The corresponding theme folder will be located under `/usr/share/themes/MBuntu-Y`. Now make a copy of the original theme (a better option would be to create a copy of the original theme in your `~/themes` folder):

   ```
   sudo cp -r /usr/share/themes/MBuntu-Y /usr/share/themes/MBuntu-Y-original
   ```
3. Next edit the CSS file:

   ```
   sudo gedit /usr/share/themes/MBuntu-Y/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css
   ```
4. Search for `overshoot` in the file, and edit the corresponding rule to read like below:

```css
    .overshoot { background: transparent; border:none; }
```

Once you have saved the file you might need to relogin to see the changes.

Comment: +1 been hunting for this answer for ages and this worked perfectly, thank you! finally got rid of that annoying effect.